# Increment integer on save in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, save, increment

I have the following code in my Rails 3 application:

```
 def like
    @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
    Suggestion.update_all("votes = (votes + 1)")
    redirect_to suggestions_url
  end

  def dislike
    @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
    Suggestion.update_all("votes = (votes - 1)")
    redirect_to suggestions_url
  end
```

It's working, but rather than updating the current suggestion it's updating them all. So I changed it to:

```
 def like
    @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
    @suggestion.update_all("votes = (votes + 1)")
    redirect_to suggestions_url
  end

  def dislike
    @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
    @suggestion.update_all("votes = (votes - 1)")
    redirect_to suggestions_url
  end
```

but then I get:

```
undefined method `update_all' for #<Suggestion:0x007f87c2b918a0>
```

So then I tried `@suggestion.update_attribute(:votes, '1')` but that resets the value to 1 instead of incrementing it.

What's the correct way to achieve this? I just want the integer (votes) of the current suggestion to increment/decrease by 1 on each save.

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
def like
 @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
 @suggestion.increment(:votes)
 redirect_to suggestions_url
end
```

Comment: Suggestion is the class
@suggestion is the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things.  It sounds like what you want is a controller action that increments an attribute by one.  You were probably closest with the code

```
@suggestion.update_attribute(:votes, '1')
```

If you check the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attribute) for that method, it sets the value of the attribute `votes` to the second arguement, the string `'1'`, on the object, `@suggestion`, and its corresponding row in the database.  Instead of setting it to `'1'`, you want to set it to the incremented value:

```
@suggestion.update_attribute(:votes, @suggestion.votes + 1)
```

Ethan suggested using the convenience method, [increment!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment!), which works just the same.

Now, if you wanted to actually auto-increment each time the object gets saved (as in something else about the object gets altered, you'd want to use the `:before_save` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) with `increment` [without the bang](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment).

Comment: I've changed my accepted answer to this one purely because the explanation helped me more than the original answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

This seems more suitable in the model. I suggest creating a `like` method inside the model like so:

```
def like
    self.increment!(:votes)
end
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
@suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
@suggestion.like
```

Note: increment!, with the exclamation point also performs the save action